# Loop will not add total

Tags: java

Making a grade book that will work for one student, it take student's name as input. Then they are asked to input grades into three categories: Homework, Quizzes, and Tests. The grades in each category will each be averaged and at the end, the formula "Final Average = 0.25*HomeworkAvg + 0.25QuizAvg + 0.50TestAvg = 65

Everything is working properly BUT -1 is not ending the process! It's frustrating!

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Assignment3

{
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{ 
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    int homeworkGrades;
    int quizGrades;
    int testGrades;
    int choice;
    int total;
    double average;
    String name;

    total = 0;
    homeworkGrades = 0;

        System.out.println( "Enter 1 or 2: \n 1 - Average grades \n 2 - Quit" ); 
        choice = input.nextInt();

        if ( choice == 1 ) {
            System.out.println( "Enter the students name" );
            name = input.next();



            System.out.println( " What would you like to do? \n 1 - Homework grades \n 2 - Quiz grades \n 3 - Test grades " );
            choice = input.nextInt();

            {

                while ( choice == 1 ) {
                    System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
                    homeworkGrades += input.nextInt();

                    if ( homeworkGrades != -1 ) //it's something going on right here :s

                    if ( homeworkGrades == -1 )
                        System.out.println("Total for homework grades is " + homeworkGrades );      
                }
            }
        }

    else if ( choice == 2 ) {
        System.out.println( "Exiting program" );
    }

    else {
        System.out.println( "Invalid response, exiting program." ); 
    }       
}
```

}

Comment: Check the code again, it has a defect.

Comment: Imagine I enter this `90, 86, 50, -1`. homeworkGrades is now 225, not -1 like you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`( homeworkGrades == -1 )` will always be false. That is why  your code is not working.

Change your code to:

```
while ( choice == 1 ) {
    int val = -2;
    System.out.println( "Enter a homework grade. Press -1 when finished" );
    while (val != -1) {
        val = input.nextInt();
        homeworkGrades += val;
    }
    System.out.println("Total for homework grades is " + homeworkGrades );
}
```

Comment: How can I make it to where if they enter -1, then it will end, show them the total and allow them to move on

Comment: You need 2 variables, one for the total amount of grades and another for your loop condition. Right now they are the same.

Comment: This worked, thanks! All you did was create an integer inside of the while?

Comment: Yes. As the user types values, as long as the value is not -1, you need to add it to the homework grades. The notion of *as long as* translates to updating the variable inside the while loop. The second important point is mentioned by @Takendarkk: you needed two variables.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Also can I ask, why did you set the int val = -2; ?

Comment: Basically, I needed something to initialize `val`, and it had to be a number that is not -1, and cannot be confused with an actual grade.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has `if ( homeworkGrades != -1 )` followed immediately by `if ( homeworkGrades == -1 )` - this is probably not going to do what you want it to do.

I recommend always putting braces around your if statements and using proper code indenting to avoid bugs like this - it'll become a lot easier to detect them on a readthrough.

Answer (score 0):

The code contain loop condition at :

`while ( choice == 1 )` -> IF choice value is 1 then thr will be infinite loop.

First update this and add bracket in

```
if ( homeworkGrades != -1 )
{
 // Add ..
}
if ( homeworkGrades == -1 )
{
   System.out.println("Total for homework grades is " + homeworkGrades );   
}
```